# inline asm type mismatch

Tags: linux, gcc, 64-bit

I am trying to make my own read system call for a 64bit linux system. but it keeps telling me I have a bad type. Is the compiler trying to indirectly address buf? I have a feeling I messed up in my input constraints. I just need the address of buf at `%2`.

**error:**

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:28: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'


static int myread(int fd, char *buf, int size) {
    register int bytes;

    asm(
    "movq $0, %%rax\n"

    "movq %1, %%rdi\n"
    "movq %2, %%rsi\n"
    "movq %3, %%rdx\n"
    "syscall\n"

    "movq %%rax, %0"

    : "=r" (bytes)
    : "m" (fd), "m" (buf), "m" (size)
    : "%rax", "%rdi", "%rsi", "%rdx"
    );

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: You will get those errors if `int` is a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mystical said, the mismatch error comes from the fact that you are using `movq` (which is for 64bit values) on 32bit integers (like fd and size).

But beyond that, this code is *really* inefficient and subtly (but dangerously) flawed.  Maybe something more like this:

```
static int myread(int fd, char *buf, int size) {
    register int bytes;

    asm(
       "syscall"

    : "=a" (bytes)
    : "D" (fd), "S" (buf), "d" (size), "0" (0)
    : "rcx", "r11", "memory", "cc"
    );

    return bytes;
}
```

To understand this, check out the [machine constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) for i386.

Note that syscalls clobber the rcx and r11 registers.  Failing to advise the compiler that you are changing these values can lead to very strange problems.  And the problems won't happen on the syscall, but a hundred lines downstream.

I'm also going to make a pitch for NOT using inline asm.  I'm not sure why you don't want to just use the system calls, but you are just setting yourself up for grief.

Comment: I am writing a trivial shell program for academic purposes only. https://github.com/MrOutput/learning/blob/master/shell/shell.c it also seems that gcc cannot further optimize my code without messing up something. In the AMD64 abi I could not find any info about which registers are clobbered by certain syscalls. Can you please point me in the direction of learning on my own? Thank you for your time!

Comment: aha I just found it  in A.2.1

Comment: I find that learning the low level details really helps me program better at higher levels. I find these trivial programs to be very enlightening for me.

Comment: Using inline asm does help understand how things work, both in the compiler and in the OS.  My concern is that people try to use this in production code.  My own initial efforts with inline asm were based on the (mistaken) belief that I could "tune things up" to squeeze a bit more perf from my innermost loop.  Nope.

Comment: true! but I am sure your efforts did not go in vain. you must have learned a lot. I wrote the shell in asm too i tried making the toupper function branchless but couldn't figure out how to do it. Please critique it if you have time, I would really appreciate it! https://github.com/MrOutput/learning/blob/master/shell/shell.asm

Comment: Well, I learned enough to re-write the gcc asm [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  As for the toupper, that's really a separate question.  But if the goal is to remove as many jmp/jl/jg as possible, I'd probably look at cmov.  I don't know that it's any *faster*, but it can work.  Also, since you know the size, consider walking the string backwards.  You can use the results of the `dec` to test for the jump to .loop and save yourself a `cmp`.